# Do make_cudaExtent, make_cudaPitchedPtr, make_cudaPos do anything special?

Tags: cuda

CUDA has three functions which take some individual scalar values and create a CUDA-Runtime-API-specific structures with those values:

```
__host__ ​cudaExtent make_cudaExtent ( size_t w, size_t h, size_t d );
__host__ ​cudaPitchedPtr make_cudaPitchedPtr ( void* d, size_t p, size_t xsz, size_t ysz );
__host__ ​cudaPos make_cudaPos ( size_t x, size_t y, size_t z );
```

Do these functions do anything other than what we could do ourselves as:

```
cudaExtent { w, h, d };
cudaPitchedPtr { d, p, xsz, ysz };
cudaPos { x, y, z };
```

? That is, does CUDA "bless" the created structures somehow? On the one hand, it doesn't seem like there should be any such "blessing"; but then - why have an API for this? I mean, not all CUDA API-related structures have this kind of constructor functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do these functions do anything other than what we could do ourselves .... ?

No.  To pick an example, you can see exactly what `make_cudaExtent` does by looking at its definition in the CUDA header file `driver_functions.h`

> That is, does CUDA "bless" the created structures somehow?

No.

> .... why have an API for this?

That would require speculation on the motivation of the CUDA development team that you, I, and anyone else other than maybe Ian Buck, Nick Wilt, Mike Murphy, Norbert Juffa and a couple of others might be privy to or recall.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized they're actually defined in a `.h` file. ... and it's a header file all of their own. Weird.

Comment: I had no hand in this, but these `struct` types may have been intended as opaque data types, with all access through functions only. I seem to recall that these kind of `make*` "constructors" were a common idiom back when CUDA was first created. The idiom may have fallen out of favor since. The iterative user feedback driven development of CUDA and its associated libraries has led to all kinds of minor inconsistencies over the years.